# How to replace a string found by awk

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I have a nginx file and this block specifically,

```
upstream jira.example.com {
## Can be connected with "nginx-proxy" network
 server 172.21.0.5:80;
```

Basically I want to replace ipaddress and port of above block out of nginx file which many contain other upstream blocks with same ip:port as well.

I use below to get the exact block,

```
awk '/upstream jira.example.com *{/{c=1; print;next} c&&/{/{c++} c&&/}/{c--} c' /etc/nginx.conf
```

and now I want to replace the IP:port like 192.168.0.2:8080; Not sure if this can be done with awk and sed inline editing.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to prefer the `sed`, that can back up original file when replacing the content in the file.

```
sed -i s/regexp/replacement/ /path/to/the/file
```

[sed man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I want to update the ip of this block (upstream jira.example.com) and not the ips of the other blocks. I have another script which will look into this file and update the upstream jira.example.com's ip:port. The program doesn't read old ip so it just replace whatever server value with new server ip:port

Comment: @Shankar you can `sed` with a regex matching your need: replace first occurence following a string like 'upstream jira.example.com' - @Kanaza: please adapt your answer

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get this working by,
sed -i '/upstream jira.example.com/{n;n;n;s/server.*/server 1.2.3.4:8080;/}' /etc/nginx.conf

Comment: you can post a self answer ;)